# Many to one select statement?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpql

How to select with relationship is many to one in JPA

in Many to One How to do select statement example

Student - Class
student is many to one class
class is one to many student

in class i can select

```
select c from Class c where c.studentid = :studentid
```

if if in student it have instance of Class?

how i do the same select statement about with Student ?

Comment: What is the question exactly? What did you try? What problem did you face?

Comment: i solved my problem with below answer ! Thank you Pascal :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking, but how about?

```
Select s from Student s where s.class.id = :classId
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written the sample query, it looks that class is many to one to student.

Assuming the relationship that you have mentioned, the queries will be

For students of the class (where to be put at per the restriction)

```
  select c.students from class c
```